# If Textview is null or empty

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm beginner in xamarin's projects. So please be patient with me. Ι want to check if textview is null or empty.I'm using this code but it doesnt work.

```
TextView textview2 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView2);
TextView textview1 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
if (textview1 != null)
{
 textview2.Text = "123";
}
else
{

}
```

Comment: maybe you're checking on `textView1` and setting text on `textView2`? Also, right way to set text is `textView.setText()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do instead

> if (textview1.Text != null &&
>   textview1.Text.equals("")) {  ...  }

because textview1 alone is the actual textview object which is not null.

Comment: Same error:  get an error: textview1 does not contain definition for getText

Comment: Edited my answer. Check it out

Answer (score 1):

Replace `if (textview1 != null)` with `if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textview1.Text))`

Answer (score 0):

I'd normally go;

```
if(textview1.getText().toString().length() > 0){...}
```