# How do I conditionally enable a TextView based on another TextView's contents?

Tags: java, android, textview

I'm new to Android Studio, and programming an application.

I'm experimenting with it, and I want to know how you can enable (for example) `Textview2` if `Textview1` contains something.

I tried this code but it didn't work:

```
TextView2.setEnabled(false);

    if (TextView1.length() > 0) {
        TextView2.setEnabled(true);
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Rewrote title, edited content down a little bit for readability and formatting.

Comment: Are you using Fragments for this or this TextView is in an Activity ?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO, You can use [contains method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) for check if your string has specific text.

```
if (TextView1.getText().toString().contains("yourText")) {
    TextView2.setEnabled(true);
}
```

for checking if Textview1 has text. you can use method for checking:

```
//usage: 
if(TextView1.getText().toString() != null || TextView1.getText().toString().length() > 0) //then do what you want.
```

be aware of [null pointer exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38359728/if-textview-is-null-or-empty) by checking `textview` have a text.

Comment: Hi! this Code does not work for me :( i get a lot of errors like: illegal start of expression

Comment: answer edited again. i think you put the method with usage in same place that got error.

Comment: I am not sure, but can you please add if it's written in a Fragment. If so, it should runOnUiThread() if the enabling is dynamic?

Comment: `runOnUiThread()` called when you are in another thread and need to change UI views. like when you get data from internet. in your fragment you can use ordinary code like in your activity as well.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer to my Question!

i did it like this:

```
if (TextView1.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {

//Do what you want here

}
```